# Trying to implement Gaussian Filter in C

Tags: c, gaussian

I am trying to implement the Gaussian Filter in C. My output layout keeps coming out wrong, I tried playing with the rows and columns in my for loops but it didn't work. The output layout should look like this:

```
0.0161464   0.0294206   0.0359344   0.0294206   0.0161464   
0.0294206   0.0536078   0.0654768   0.0536078   0.0294206   
0.0359344   0.0654768   0.0799735   0.0654768   0.0359344   
0.0294206   0.0536078   0.0654768   0.0536078   0.0294206   
0.0161464   0.0294206   0.0359344   0.0294206   0.0161464
```

(This is just an example of of a Gaussian filter layout).

Here the output layout I am getting in my program:

```
0.114986 0.101475 0.069743 0.037331 0.015562
0.101475 0.089551 0.061548 0.032944 0.013733
0.069743 0.061548 0.042301 0.022642 0.009439
0.037331 0.032944 0.022642 0.012119 0.005052 
0.015562 0.013733 0.009439 0.005052 0.002106
```

Here is the code segment of my program:

```
for (i = 0; i < smooth_kernel_size; i++) {
    for (j = -0; j < smooth_kernel_size; j++) {
        gauss[i][j] = K * exp(((pow((i), 2) + pow((j), 2)) / ((2 * pow(sigma, 2)))) * (-1));
        sum += gauss[i][j]; 
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < smooth_kernel_size; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < smooth_kernel_size; j++) {
        gauss[i][j] /= sum;
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < smooth_kernel_size; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < smooth_kernel_size; j++) {
        printf("%f ", gauss[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Will appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computation is incorrect: the filter should be centered on the origin. Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define smooth_kernel_size 5
#define sigma 1.0
#define K  1

int main() {
    double gauss[smooth_kernel_size][smooth_kernel_size];
    double sum = 0;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < smooth_kernel_size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < smooth_kernel_size; j++) {
            double x = i - (smooth_kernel_size - 1) / 2.0;
            double y = j - (smooth_kernel_size - 1) / 2.0;
            gauss[i][j] = K * exp(((pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2)) / ((2 * pow(sigma, 2)))) * (-1));
            sum += gauss[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < smooth_kernel_size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < smooth_kernel_size; j++) {
            gauss[i][j] /= sum;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < smooth_kernel_size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < smooth_kernel_size; j++) {
            printf("%f ", gauss[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
0.002969 0.013306 0.021938 0.013306 0.002969
0.013306 0.059634 0.098320 0.059634 0.013306
0.021938 0.098320 0.162103 0.098320 0.021938
0.013306 0.059634 0.098320 0.059634 0.013306
0.002969 0.013306 0.021938 0.013306 0.002969
```

Note also that the main expression can be simplified:

```
    gauss[i][j] = K * exp(-(x * x + y * y) / (2 * sigma * sigma));
```

Answer (score 3):

Well the problem is with the way you calculate the gaussian filter you  should use symmetric points i suppose -2 -1 0 1 2 for eg,
Second i think tht's the correct formula

```
int length = smooth_kernel_size/2;
for (int i = -length ; i <=length ; i++)
    {
        for(int j=-length ; j <=length ; j++)
        {   //here
            gauss[i+length][j+length]= K * exp(-1*((pow((i), 2) + pow((j), 2)) / ((2 * pow(sigma, 2))))) / (M_PI * 2 * pow(sigma, 2));
            sum += gauss[i + length][j +length];
        }
    }
```